# R ggplot - Shade between 2 horizontal lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I would like to shade between 2 horizontal lines. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2) 
library(lubridate)

set.seed(10)
dat <- tibble(Month = seq(12), Year = 2018, N = rnorm(12))
N1 <- min(dat$N) + 1
N2 <- max(dat$N) - 1

MyPlot <- ggplot(data = dat, mapping = aes(x = as.Date(YearMonth), y = N)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_ribbon(xmin = as.Date(-Inf, origin="1970-01-01"), xmax = as.Date(Inf, origin="1970-01-01"),
                  ymin = N1, ymax = N2,
                  fill = "orange", alpha = 0.2
                  ) +
      scale_x_date(date_labels = "%B", breaks = "1 month") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1)) +
      labs(x = "Month")

print(MyPlot)
```

I get the warning:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: xmin, xmax
```

This warning comes from:

```
xmin = as.Date(-Inf, origin="1970-01-01"), xmax = as.Date(Inf, origin="1970-01-01")
```

I get the following plot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVWtA.jpg)

I would like to shade on all the X axis. I can't do it due to the fact X axis is a date. Does someone have an idea on how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I replace the function

```
geom_ribbon()
```

By the function

```
annotate()
```